# bukkit command recognised n

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a plugin with essential commands for a server, and I have put in a couple of events which are working fine. But when I try to add commands, it doesn't work. (Before you ask, I've replaced everything in the onCommand section with a simple sendMessage, and it doesn't do anything). When I execute the command, it just tells me the usage I have put in the plugin.yml.

Here is my code: sorry it's really long

```
package com.pepsi.core;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

@Override
public void onEnable() {

    Bukkit.getLogger().info("PepsiCore >> Enabled!");
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

    getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
    saveConfig();

}

@Override
public void onDisable() {

    Bukkit.getLogger().info("PepsiCore >> Disabled!");

}

public boolean onCommand(Command cmd, CommandSender sender, String cmdLbl, String[] args) {

    if (args.length == 0) {
        sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eNot enough arguments! Use &6/pcore help &e to see a list of commands!"));
        return false;
    }

    if (args.length == 1) {

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&8--------------------<&6&lPepsiCore&8>--------------------"));
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&6/pcore help &8>> &eDisplays the help page"));
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&6/pcore info &8>> &eDisplays the plugin info page"));
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&6/pcore ranks &8>> &eDisplays all the ranks"));
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&6/pcore setrank <player> <rank> &8>> &eDisplays all the ranks"));
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&8--------------------<&6&lPepsiCore&8>--------------------"));
            return true;
        }

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("info")) {
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&8--------------------<&6&lPepsiCore&8>--------------------"));
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&ePepsiCore version &61.0.0-BETA"));
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&eDeveloped by &6P3pi &efor &6Project: Infernal"));
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&8--------------------<&6&lPepsiCore&8>--------------------"));
            return true;
        }

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ranks")) {
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eRanks: &6guest&e, &6gold&e, &6diamond&e, &6emerald&e, &6yt&e, &6staff&e, &6developer&e, &6owner"));
            return false;
        }

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setrank")) {
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eNot enough arguments! Use &6/pcore help&e to see a list of commands!"));
            return false;
        }

        sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eInvalid arguments! Use &6/pcore help&e to see a list of commands!"));
        return false;
    }

    if (args.length == 2) {

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setrank")) {
            sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eNot enough arguments! Use &6/pcore help&e to see a list of commands!"));
            return false;
        }

        sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eInvalid arguments! Use &6/pcore help&e to see a list of commands!"));
        return false;
    }

    if (args.length == 3) {

        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setrank")) {

            Player t = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[1]);
            if (t == null) {
                sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eThe player &6" + args[1] + " &eis not online at the moment!"));
                return false;
            }

            String uuid = t.getUniqueId().toString();
            String rank = args[2];

            if (rank == ("guest")) { getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, rank); }
            else if (rank == ("gold")) { getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, rank); }
            else if (rank == ("diamond")) { getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, rank); }
            else if (rank == ("emerald")) { getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, rank); }
            else if (rank == ("yt")) { getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, rank); }
            else if (rank == ("staff")) { getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, rank); }
            else if (rank == ("developer")) { getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, rank); }
            else if (rank == ("owner")) { getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, rank); }
            else { sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eThe rank &6" + rank + " &e does not exist! Use &6/pcore ranks &eto see a list of ranks!")); }

        }

        sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eInvalid arguments! Use &6/pcore help&e to see a list of commands!"));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {

    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    String uuid = p.getUniqueId().toString();
    String name = p.getName();
    String msg = e.getMessage();

    String rank = (String) getConfig().get("ranks." + uuid);

    if (rank == "guest") { e.setFormat(Util.transMsg("&fGuest &7&l" + name + " &8>> &f" + msg)); }
    else if (rank == "gold") { e.setFormat(Util.transMsg("&eGold &6&l" + name + " &8>> &e" + msg)); }
    else if (rank == "diamond") { e.setFormat(Util.transMsg("&bDiamond &3&l" + name + " &8>> &b" + msg)); }
    else if (rank == "emerald") { e.setFormat(Util.transMsg("&aEmerald &2&l" + name + " &8>> &a" + msg)); }
    else if (rank == "yt") { e.setFormat(Util.transMsg("&dYouTuber &5&l" + name + " &8>> &d" + msg)); }
    else if (rank == "staff") { e.setFormat(Util.transMsg("&9Staff &1&l" + name + " &8>> &9" + msg)); }
    else if (rank == "developer") { e.setFormat(Util.transMsg("&cDeveloper &4&l" + name + " &8>> &c" + msg)); }
    else if (rank == "owner") { e.setFormat(Util.transMsg("&cOwner &4&l" + name + " &8>> &c" + msg)); }
    else { e.setCancelled(true); p.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eYour rank seems to be broken! Please let a member of staff know!")); }

}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {

    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    String uuid = p.getUniqueId().toString();

    if (p.hasPlayedBefore() == false) {
        getConfig().set("ranks." + uuid, "guest");
        saveConfig();
        return;
    }

}

}
```

and here is my plugin.yml:

```
name: PepsiCore
author: P3pi
version: 1.0.3
main: com.pepsi.core.Main

commands:
    pcore:
        description: Core command
        usage: /pcore
    pepsicore:
        description: Core command
        usage: /pepsicore
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that Bukkit handles commands is it runs the `onCommand` method of your JavaPlugin class. Specifically the `onCommand` method that takes the arguments `CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args`

Your method has the arguments in the wrong order, as Vlexing mentioned, so it's not running your method when the command is run, so instead running the `onCommand` method from `JavaPlugin` which only contains `return false;`. Bukkit still recognizes your command because of your plugin.yml, but when it tried to run your method it got `false` so it printed out your usage message.

Basically, just fix the order of your arguments and follow Vlexing's answer and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

When writing code in the `onCommand()` method, the code block should always `return true`, in examples such as:

```
  if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ranks")) {
        sender.sendMessage(Util.transMsg("&e<!> &6&lPepsiCore &8>> &eRanks: &6guest&e, &6gold&e, &6diamond&e, &6emerald&e, &6yt&e, &6staff&e, &6developer&e, &6owner"));
        return false;
    }
```

You use `return false;` which will give you the `plugin.yml` usage.

Please see [this spigot thread talking about the same issue](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/command-returning-usage-message.80328/).

Please see [this bukkit thread talking about the same issue](https://bukkit.org/threads/command-only-returning-usage.53647/).

Comment: I've done what you said and it still has the exact same issue...all the return falses in the onCommand section are now return true and still not working, and also tried with the one right at the bottom being return false and the rest return true.... help please?

Comment: I also noticed that for your onCommand() args you have `Command cmd, CommandSender sender, String cmdLbl, String[] args`. The correct way to have the args is `public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {}`. Don't actually know if that will help with your main problem but I would like to point that out.

Comment: Thanks @Vlexing, I didn't know that made a difference but when I changed it it worked perfectly. I thought you could call the commandLabel etc what you wanted but thanks for the help :)